# Get site collection administrator for one drive

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, onedrive-for-business

I have this weird thing going on with my tenant. I have successfully executed this PowerShell command on other tenants to retrieve Site collection administrators for user one drive for business. However, one particular tenant, I cannot get any return when executing the same command.

**working**

```
Get-SPOUser -Site https://sitename-my.sharepoint.com/personal/testuser1_testuser1_onmicrosoft_com | where {$_.IsSiteAdmin}
```

**not working**

```
Get-SPOUser -Site https://myplace.mss.com/personal/testuser1_mss_com | where {$_.IsSiteAdmin}
```

Is it the way the URL is named for mysite????

Comment: Do you get any error? what error do you get, please add details? You can try this Get-SPOUser -Site https://yourtenant-my.sharepoint.com | where {$_.IsSiteAdmin} or | select * to see everything.

Comment: I ran Get-SPOUser -Site https://myplace.mss.com/personal/testuser1_mss_com | where {$_.IsSiteAdmin}

Comment: I got nothing coming back. Same result as other command. 
It works fine if I run on another tenant. The only different is my one drive URL is https://myplace.mss.com/personal/testuser1_mss_com  instead of yourtenantname-my.sharepoint.com/personal/testuser1_testuser1_onmicrosoft_com. That is the only different with the way the URL was registered for mysite/onedrive.

Comment: This is the result that I got from another tenant

Get-SPOUser -Site https://test99-my.sharepoint.com/personal/testuser1_testuser1_onmicrosoft
_com | where {$_.IsSiteAdmin}

Display Name   Login Name                      Groups
------------   ----------                      ------
Testuser 1 Testuser1@test99.onmicrosoft.com  {}
Testuser 2      Testuser1@test99.onmicrosoft.com  {}

Comment: Have you tried any other commands?

Comment: Other commands works fine. I ran the same command on my sandbox tenant and it works fine. However, doesn't work on my production tenant.

Answer (score -1):

You need to be a site admin yourself to have it show the property as TRUE.